# How to change docker logging format

Tags: docker, logging, docker-compose, dockerfile

As of now we have Spring boot applications which are running in docker containers - and the docker containers are adding the logs of the application in the below format
i.e. the log written by the application is placed in the field called "log" and docker adds the other two fields stdout and timestamp.

Can any one suggest how to remove this additional meta data added by docker and instead have what ever logged by application in the logs as it is.

{
"log": "Some log data",
"stream": "stdout",
"time": "2022-03-15T22:56:36.376013325Z"
}

Comment: Docker doesn't manipulate the output of containers at all.  If you were running this under Docker Compose you might see the container name at the start of the line, but Docker doesn't know anything about applications' log formats and it won't try to change things into a JSON syntax.

Comment: Where are you seeing this specific format?  If it's in the Docker-internal `/var/lib/docker` tree somewhere, can you use a tool like `jq` to extract the `log` items back out?  (Log-management tools like Fluentd that can read the Docker-internal JSON-lines-format logs should know how to do this on their own.)